# My textures in my render look different than in the preview render 2.8 (Solved

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, uv

[image]

[image]

I don't know why my render looks different than in the preview. Got any help?

edit: I fixed it, some guy gave me some pointers and figured it out

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1csDJXr-VCrQtxWk7Uk73j0PG8rpHDld4?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey, it looks like you forgot to pack your textures with the .blend file. Without them, it's all just pink. I think your issue might have to do with transparency, but I can't check. Would you mind packing the textures and uploading again?

Comment: I packed the textures now.

Comment: I sent an access request.

Comment: Oh I just forgot to set it to not restricted